# Wrap Data.Vec types

Tags: haskell, types

I'd like to wrap some of the types of `Data.Vec` in my own types but it doesn't seem to work. For example, I'd like to have my own `Vec3` that would be a `Vec3F` so I did something like this:

**Types.h**:

```
module Types
( Vec3(..)
) where

import qualified Data.Vec as V

type Vec3 = V.Vec3 Float
```

**Main.hs**:

```
import Types

vect :: Vec3
vect = Vec3 3 2 4

main = return ()
```

GHC complains and gives me this error:

```
Main.hs:4:8: Not in scope: data constructor `Vec3'
```

Is it because my new type has the same name as a type of `Data.Vec` despite the fact that I did a qualified import?

If so is there way of doing this without changing the name of my type?

If not, how can I export from my `Types` module only some types of `Data.Vec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vec3` is not a data constructor, it's a [type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-vec3-0.1.0.1/docs/Data-Vec3.html) (in this case, a `class`).  Perhaps you could wrap your own wrapper around the constructor to achieve what you want?

```
makeVec :: (Double,Double,Double) -> Vec3
makeVec = V.fromXYZ -- TODO some float mangling
```

Comment: You are using the package [simple-vec3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-vec3-0.1.0.1) but I want to use [Vec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Vec). The problem is that I can construct a `V.Vec3F` directly like this: `V.Vec3F 3 5 2` whereas it doesn't work with my own `Vec3` defined as `type Vec3 = V.Vec3F`.

Comment: @ElieGnrd Your `Vec3` is not a data constructor, only a type constructor.  You can't construct values with it at all.  If I say that `type IntList = [Int]`, I still have to use the data constructors for `[Int]` to construct something of type `IntList` because it's just an alias.  Another example would be `type Environment = Data.Map.Map String String`, I can have a value of type `Environment`, but it's indistinguishable from a value of type `Data.Map.Map String String` and either can be used in the other's place.  It's just another name for the same type, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks! That made me understand some things.